# Configurar acesso externo a um servidor Magento local

Tags: magento, servidor, configuração, virtualbox

Tenho um servidor Ubuntu 64 bit configurado numa máquina virtual (Virtualbox) usando o pacote de instalação do Bitnami com Magento.
Consigo acessar normalmente a aplicação através de qualquer computador na minha rede através do endereço local da instalação (ex.: 192.168.25.30).

O desafio aqui seria configurar para que eu consiga acessar de fora dessa rede, através da internet. Já pesquisei alguns tópicos de port-forwading, rede NAT e afins.

Minhas configurações:

> Windows 8.1 como SO principal;
>
> Servidor Linux Ubuntu 64 bit (Virtualbox);
>
> Pacote de instalação do Magento do site Bitnami;
>
> Na configuração de rede da máquina virtual, deixei em modo bridge;
>
> Fiz o redirecionamento de porta vindo da porta 80 para o ip destino local do servidor na porta 80 também (não preenchi o ip de origem pois fiquei em dúvida se deveria colocar o ip externo);

Alguém já configurou algo parecido ou tem alguma alternativa melhor para exibir o que foi desenvolvido no Magento sem que eu tenha uma hospedagem?

Comment: Você pode liberar sua porta de entrada 80 e ligar ela a seu PC, se for um caso de uso simples que imagino que seja sugiro utilizar algo como [hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/BR/products/hamachi/)

Comment: Eu liberei a porta 80, mas ainda não tentei o Hamachi por necessitar de ter que instalá-lo na máquina das pessoas que irão acessar o site. Em último caso o farei.